# JavaHL Mac 10.8 no Xcode

Tags: java

I have OS X 10.8 and I've been tasked to program for the Android platform in Eclipse for the duration of the semester. Apple did not include Xcode (Nor is it available for 10.8.x) and I cannot install JavaHL via MacPorts without it.

I have XQuartz installed to handle any Xcode-based applications, but macports doesn't know about it.

> Creating port index in /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports
>   Error: 
>   Error: No Xcode installation was found.
>   Error: Please install Xcode and/or run xcode-select to specify its location.
>   Error: 
>   Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute
>   Adding port lang/rust

Does anyone have a step-by-step resolution for this problem?

> Failed to load JavaHL Library.
>   These are the errors that were encountered:
>   no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
>   Native Library /opt/subversion/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.0.dylib already loaded in another classloader
>   no svnjavahl in java.library.path
>   java.library.path = .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java

Comment: Whats stopping you from installing XCode yourself? Its available in the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)

Answer (score 1):

You do not necessarily need `JavaHL` to use Subversion repositories within Eclipse. Eclipse provides [several connectors](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/connectors_discovery.php), with the ones that are based on [`SVNKit`](http://svnkit.com/) being coded in pure Java. That would allow you to sidestep the issue with the missing `JavaHL` library.